# Messages received from port in erlang-sqlite3

Tags: erlang, erlang-ports

Erlang-sqlite3 uses a port driver to connect with the SQLite database, and [receives messages from the port](http://github.com/alexeyr/erlang-sqlite3/blob/56bfbe484d0c5b97d7b1f08677def3cc388787be/src/sqlite3.erl#L609):

```
wait_result(Port) ->
  receive
    {Port, Reply} ->
      % io:format("Reply: ~p~n", [Reply]),
      Reply;
    {error, Reason} ->
      io:format("Error: ~p~n", [Reason]),
      {error, Reason};
    _Else ->
      io:format("Else: ~p~n", [_Else]),
      _Else
  end.
```

I thought that messages from ports should look like [this](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/ports.html):

```
{Port,{data,Data}}    Data is received from the external program.
{Port,closed}         Reply to Port ! {Pid,close}.
{Port,connected}      Reply to Port ! {Pid,{connect,NewPid}}
{'EXIT',Port,Reason}  If the port has terminated for some reason.
```

So, when uncommenting the `io:format` line in `{Port, Reply}` clause, I should expect to see `{data, ...}` for actual replies. I don't; instead I see (for `test.erl`)

```
Reply: {ok,101}
Reply: [{columns,["name"]},{rows,[{<<"user">>}]}]
Reply: [{columns,["sql"]},
        {rows,[{<<"CREATE TABLE user (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, age INTEGER, wage INTEGER)">>}]}]
Reply: {id,1}
Reply: {id,2}
Reply: [{columns,["id","name","age","wage"]},
        {rows,[{1,<<"abby">>,20,2000},{2,<<"marge">>,30,2000}]}]
Reply: [{columns,["id","name","age","wage"]},{rows,[{1,<<"abby">>,20,2000}]}]
Reply: [{columns,["id","name","age","wage"]},
        {rows,[{1,<<"abby">>,20,2000},{2,<<"marge">>,30,2000}]}]
Reply: {ok,101}
Reply: [{columns,["id","name","age","wage"]},{rows,[{1,<<"abby">>,20,2000}]}]
Reply: {ok,101}
```

1. Where am I going wrong?
2. Will messages I get on a port error look like `{'EXIT',Port,Reason}` or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant example in http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/driver.html is the last one. It turns out that when using `driver_output_term`, the term is sent by itself:

```
receive
    Result ->
        Result
end.
```

instead of

```
receive
    {Port, {data, Result}} ->
        Result
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that between your process and port is another process involved which decodes real port messages. Are you sure that Port is really Port?. Try `io:format("Port: ~p~n", [Port])` If you will see something like `#Port<0.500>` it is port, if it will be something like `<0.38.0>` there is the man in the middle.

Comment: Yes, just checked and it really is a port.

Comment: @Alexey: I don't know if linked-in drivers can't work on their own.